# Dropdown for Integer array using html:select

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have been working on stuts app where I'm using an Integer ArrayList. I need to create a dropdown to list the arraylist.

I have been trying using html:select --> html:optioncollection.

But I am getting error of `Cannot create iterator for com.SelectTagForm@18488ef`.

code:

```
<html:optionsCollection name="selectTagForm" 
label="grade" value="grade" />
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is the piece of code that is throwing the exception. It's from the `optionsCollection` tag.

```
protected Iterator getIterator(Object collection)
  throws JspException {
  if (collection.getClass().isArray()) {
    collection = Arrays.asList((Object[]) collection);
  }
  if (collection instanceof Collection) {
    return (((Collection) collection).iterator());
  } else if (collection instanceof Iterator) {
    return ((Iterator) collection);
  } else if (collection instanceof Map) {
    return (((Map) collection).entrySet().iterator());
  } else if (collection instanceof Enumeration) {
    return new IteratorAdapter((Enumeration) collection);
  } else {
    throw new JspException(messages.getMessage(
        "optionsCollectionTag.iterator", collection.toString()));
  }
}
```

Don't know what your full setup is since you posted only one line of code, but it's obvious that you are not sending it the right collection (you are sending a `com.SelectTagForm` as the error message specifies).

Read carefully [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#optionsCollection); and [here](http://www.laliluna.de/download/struts-html-optionscollection-en.pdf) is a simple tutorial.

One other thing, this tag operates on a collection of beans, where each bean has a label property and a value property (the actual names of these properties can be configured using the `label` and `value` attributes of this tag). You can't extract something like that from an Integer ArrayList (as you specified that is your case).